# How do I increment a property of a subdocument in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, api, mongoose

I am making a route in NodeJS using Mongoose which increments the rating of a subdocument of an object. I will post the models and route code below. When I execute the query in Postman, I get an empty json object back and a 400 error. This means somewhere in the query I am doing something wrong.

**blogPost model**

```
  const BlogPostSchema = new Schema({
  content: {
    type: String,
    validate: {
      validator: (content) => content.length > 5,
      message: 'Content must contain at least 6 characters.'
    },
    required: [true, 'Content must be filled in.']
  },
  rating: Number,
  title: String,
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' },
  board: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'board'},
  comments: [commentSchema]
});

const BlogPost = mongoose.model('blogPost', BlogPostSchema);

module.exports = BlogPost;
```

**comment schema**

```
const CommentSchema = new Schema({
  content: {
    type: String,
    validate: {
      validator: (content) => content.length > 5,
      message: 'Content must contain at least 6 characters.'
    },
    required: [true, 'Content must be filled in.']
  },
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' },
  rating: Number
});

module.exports = CommentSchema;
```

**NodeJS route**

```
routes.put('/blogPosts/:id/comment/:idm', function(req, res) {
    const blogPostId = req.param('id');
    const commentId = req.param('idm');

    BlogPost.findById(blogPostId)
        .then((blogPost) => {
          blogPost.comments.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: commentId}, {$inc: {rating: 1}});
        })
        .then((blogPost) => res.status(200).json({
        'status': 'Comment rating is increased.'
    }))
    .catch((error) => res.status(400).json(error))
});
```

This is the response [PostMan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E48WQ.png)

All help is appreciated.

Comment: The `findByIdAndUpdate()` method seems like it would expect only an id for the first parameter, just going by the method name. Are you sure it shouldn't be `blogPost.comments.findByIdAndUpdate(commentId, {$inc: {rating: 1}});`? Alternatively, you could probably use the `findOneAndUpdate()` method instead. The documentation seems to agree: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate

Comment: Couple of questions/clarifications:
1. req.params instead of req.param
2. `blogPost.comments.findByIdAndUpdate` is this valid? I'm guessing because I've never worked like this before. 
3. As B. Fleming said, `findByIdAndUpdate` takes the `id` as its first parameter, you don't need to put it in as a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the error:

```
BlogPost.findById(blogPostId)
    .then((blogPost) => {
      blogPost.comments.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: commentId}, {$inc: {rating: 1}});
    })
    .then((blogPost) => res.status(200).json({
    'status': 'Comment rating is increased.'
}))
```

Should be:

```
    BlogPost.update({_id: blogPostId, 'comments._id': commentId}, {$inc:{'comments.$.rating':1}})
    .then((blogPost) => res.status(200).json({
    'status': 'Comment rating is increased.'
}))
```